# Meteor how to retrieve the value of an attribute of a collection object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the Meteor.users collection. users have an attribute called “lastQuestionAnswered”, which is the questionId of the last question that the user has answered.

```
{ "_id" : "jrCJiuo7eprNFKfLG",
"name" : "Elon Musk",
"lastQuestionAnswered" : 1 }
```

How do I extract the value of the lastQuestionAnswered attribute (of the current user) into a variable? So that in the end we have

```
Var lastAnsweredQuestionId = ???
```

I am trying to do this server-side. I have looked at related questions but could not find any hints. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you need to achieve. What means `lastQuestionAnswered`? Is is some sort of ID of question user answered? We already have `Meteor.users`. What `User` collection suppose to store?

Comment: sorry, it is the Meteor.users collection. and lastQuestionAnswered is just the questionID of the last question that the user has answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get current user on client side you need to use `Meteor.user()` method. So your code will look like:

```
var lastAnsweredQuestionId = Meteor.user().lastQuestionAnswered;
```

It will work on client side or in methods on server side (if user is logged in).

**UPDATE**

If you need to get same result in publish function you need a bit different approach because `Meteor.user()` doesn't work in publishers:

```
var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
var lastAnsweredQuestionId = currentUser.lastQuestionAnswered;
```

Comment: looks good. I need it inside a Publish function. It says I cant use Meteor.user inside a publish function. Any advice?

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work:                      `Meteor.publish('questions', function(){
  var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
  var lastQuestionAnsweredId = currentUser.lastQuestionAnswered;
  return Questions.find({number: lastQuestionAnsweredId});
});` Sorry I don't know how to make line breaks in comments

Comment: This publish method is supposed to publish the current heading of the screen. It just doesn't show up. I'll try it later on a Mac, maybe it's just some Windows compatibility problem, had that before :) Thank you for your help, will come back to you. Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I have tried it on Mac but unfortunately it still does not work. Do you have any idea where I can find additional hints to the answer? Any help is much appreciated.